# Where can I find the datasheet of LT706?

Tags: identification, datasheet

I found this Linear Technology chip with the marking "LT 706 4851". Does anyone know what kind of chip this is and/or where I can find the datasheet? I suspect it is in a SOIC-8 package and might be more than 15 years old.

[image: LT 706 4851]

Exclusions: LTC1706, LTC3706 and LTC7060 are sold in other packages. ADM706 would have VCC and GND tied together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like an [LTC485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/485fm.pdf) RS-485 driver. The last character in 485I is the letter ‘I’ not a ‘1’, and tells you the temperature range (-40~85’C).

The 706 is likely the date code (maybe 7th month of 2006).

Comment: Agreed. In addition, from what can be seen of the PCB layout in the photo it matches the likely connections for the LTC485. Pins 1&4 (the bottom left and right) are the single-ended logic in/outputs. Pins 2&3 (center bottom) are the enable pins for RX and TX respectively; both tied together which is commonly done. Pin 5 is ground, pin 8 is power. Pins 6&7 are the 485 bus and head off along the same path, as a differential signal should.